# NodeJS module with parameters

Tags: node.js

I want to create a module with `socket.io` parameter so I would have a globally set variable in my module class.

My question is how would one do it and still access the functions in that model class?

in term I would want something like what you can do with `socket.io` lib,
this is how you define the `socket.io` lib in the main app class and you can see that you need to pass a `server` parameter and you can use the objects funnctions.

`const io = require('socket.io')(server);`

Also this is the exact object I want to pass to my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model file:

```
var storedObject

module.exports = (myObject) => {
    if(myObject){
        // set object only if provided
        // this way you will be able to init once and use everywhere this model
        storedObject = myObject
    }

    return {
        getA: getA
    }
}

function getA(){
    return storedObject.a
}
```

Usage example:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2} // can also be a socket.io or any other object
var model= require('./model.js')(obj) // call with object only on initialization
console.log(model.getA())
```

Comment: Oh so I was missing `return` when I tried to do something like that myself, thank you very much!